# How to write data into csv file from ionic form?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native, angular-local-storage

I am newbie to Ionic.
I have two fields in the form

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input #name type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>school</ion-label>
    <ion-input #school type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<div padding>
  <button block ion-button (click)="SaveForm()">Save data</button>
</div>
```

After user clicking on the save button, I want to save the data in csv format in local file system.

I tried

```
SaveForm()
{

    var finalCSV = this.name.value+','+this.school.value;
     alert('finalCSV');
      $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'data.csv', finalCSV, true).then(function(result){
            alert('Success! Export created!');
          }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
          })

}
```

In the same ts file I have added

```
import {File} from 'ionic-native';
declare var cordova:any;

const fs:string = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
File.checkDir(this.fs, 'mydir')
    .then(_ => console.log('yay'))
    .catch(err => console.log('boooh'));
```

I am getting following Error

> Typescript Error Cannot find name '$cordovaFile'.

How to resolve this Error?

Is there any better approach to implement this?

Comment: I reckon you have to wrap your code inside $ionicPlatform.ready function.
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
$cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'data.csv', finalCSV, true).then(function(result){
            alert('Success! Export created!');
          }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
          })
    
 };

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Page, Platform} from 'ionic/ionic';    

constructor(platform: Platform) {
  this.platform = platform;
}
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'data.csv', finalCSV, true).then(function(result){
                alert('Success! Export created!');
              }, function(err) {
                console.log("ERROR");
              })
}
```

Comment: I am getting Typescript Error
Cannot find name '$ionicPlatform'. What are the required imports that we need to add to use this?

Comment: In your controller inject $ionicPlatform, $cordovaFile as a dependency. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: sorry that is for ionic1 not ionic2